# LocationRequest (FusedLocationProviderClient) - Deprecated

Tags: android, kotlin, fusedlocationproviderclient

LocationRequest is now deprecated? What is the replacement for it?

I was using it and recently got a deprecation message. What should I do now:

```
val locationRequest = LocationRequest().apply {
            interval = LOCATION_UPDATE_INTERVAL
            fastestInterval = LOCATION_FASTEST_INTERVAL
            priority = LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY
        }
        fusedLocationProviderClient.requestLocationUpdates(
            locationRequest,
            locationCallback,
            Looper.getMainLooper()
        )
```

Comment: I checked for Java, still not deprecated.

Comment: Yes, after upgrade to `com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:18.0.0` it was deprecated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use it like this

```
val locationRequest = LocationRequest.create().apply {
        interval = LOCATION_UPDATE_INTERVAL
        fastestInterval = LOCATION_FASTEST_INTERVAL
        priority = LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY
    }
```

Comment: It cannot be `nullable`, so, create()`?` is not needed. I edited the answer.

Answer (score 4):

Location services were updated to version 21.0.0, and the LocationRequest.create was deprecated with the new update.

Here is how to change LocationRequest.create to recommended LocationRequest.Builder:

```
   fun createLocationRequest() = LocationRequest.Builder(
        Priority.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY, TimeUnit.MINUTES.toMillis(5)
    ).apply {
        setGranularity(Granularity.GRANULARITY_PERMISSION_LEVEL)
        setDurationMillis(TimeUnit.MINUTES.toMillis(5))
        setWaitForAccurateLocation(true)
        setMaxUpdates(1)
    }.build()
```

Answer (score 1):

// The desired interval for location updates. Inexact. Updates may be more or less frequent.

```
  private const val UPDATE_INTERVAL_IN_MILLISECONDS: Long = 5000
  val  locationRequest = LocationRequest.Builder(
        Priority.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY, UPDATE_INTERVAL_IN_MILLISECONDS
    ).build()
```